# DisallowedRedirect: Unsafe redirect to URL with protocol '127.0.0.1'

Tags: python, django, web, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get my Django application running, and stuck at the following error at all of my endpoints (except the root endpoint):

```
DisallowedRedirect at /coffeeshop/items
Unsafe redirect to URL with protocol '127.0.0.1'
```

With the server logs saying:

```
Unsafe redirect to URL with protocol '127.0.0.1'
Bad Request: 127.0.0.1:80/myapp/items
[01/Jun/2020 16:12:36] "GET /myapp/items HTTP/1.1" 400 65131
```

Here is the `myapp/items` view:

```
class ItemViewSet(ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    model = Item
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = ItemFilterSet
```

The server is running on http://127.0.0.1:8000/, and I am not trying to redirect anything in any of my views. As can be seen in the logs, the server tries to redirect the request to `:80` port, and I don't understand why.

Here is my settings file, too, for reference (maybe there are problems that I cannot see):

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    'localhost',
    'localhost:3000',
    '127.0.0.1',
    '0.0.0.0'
]

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # 'jet_django',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp.apps.MyappConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    'phonenumber_field',
    'django_filters',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": os.environ.get("POSTGRES_DB"),
        "USER": os.environ.get("POSTGRES_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("POSTGRES_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": os.environ.get("POSTGRES_HOST"),
        "PORT": os.environ.get("POSTGRES_PORT"),
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# CORS
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = ('DELETE', 'GET', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'PUT')
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost',
    'http://127.0.0.1',
)
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

Comment: It looks like you direct to `127.0.0.1/...`, and thus not specifies the protocol, for example `https://127.0.0.1/...`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I just included ```http://127.0.0.1``` to the ```ALLOWED_HOSTS```, didn't work out.